# How can I join/merge 2 DataFrames, keeping values from the second?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames with user details and scores. Some users have a second score and will be present in the second DataFrame. What I want to do is to join or merge them together (don't really mind which) to get their final score i.e. if they exist in the second DataFrame then take it from there, otherwise from the first.

DataFrame one:

```
    first_name  last_name              email  score               feedback
0         Bill      First  user1@example.com   57.0  Needs to try again
1         Anna     Second  user2@example.com   10.0  Not enough to proceed
2         Fred      Third  user3@example.com  100.0  Excellent!
```

DataFrame two:

```
    first_name  last_name              email  score      feedback
0         Bill      First  user1@example.com  100.0  Much better!
```

Desired result:

```
    first_name  last_name              email  score               feedback
0         Bill      First  user1@example.com  100.0  Much better!
1         Anna     Second  user2@example.com   10.0  Not enough to proceed
2         Fred      Third  user3@example.com  100.0  Excellent!
```

The closest I've got is `df1.merge(df2, on=['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', ], how='left')` but that gives me columns: `first_name last_name email score_x feedback_x score_y feedback_y`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.concat` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
out = pd.concat([df2, df1]).drop_duplicates(['first_name', 'last_name', 'email'])
print(out)

# Output
  first_name last_name              email  score               feedback
0       Bill     First  user1@example.com  100.0           Much better!
1       Anna    Second  user2@example.com   10.0  Not enough to proceed
2       Fred     Third  user3@example.com  100.0             Excellent!
```

Assuming `first_name`, `last_name` and `email` fields are the primary key to identify records like your `merge`.

Just before `drop_duplicates`, your dataframe looks like:

```
>>> pd.concat([df2, df1])
  first_name last_name              email  score               feedback
0       Bill     First  user1@example.com  100.0           Much better!
0       Bill     First  user1@example.com   57.0     Needs to try again  # dupe
1       Anna    Second  user2@example.com   10.0  Not enough to proceed
2       Fred     Third  user3@example.com  100.0             Excellent!
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative using `combine_first`:

```
cols = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
out = df2.set_index(cols).combine_first(df1.set_index(cols)).reset_index()
```

output:

```
               email first_name last_name  score               feedback
0  user1@example.com       Bill     First  100.0           Much better!
1  user2@example.com       Anna    Second   10.0  Not enough to proceed
2  user3@example.com       Fred     Third  100.0             Excellent!
```